# CAKeyframeAnimation : contents change back to first image when stopped

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics, caanimation, cakeyframeanimation

I animate the content of a `CALayer` using the following code:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *countanimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"number3"].CGImage, 
                        (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"number2"].CGImage, 
                        (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"number1"].CGImage, nil];
[countanimation setKeyPath:@"contents"];
[countanimation setValues:images];
[countanimation setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationDiscrete];
[countanimation setDuration:3.0f];
[countanimation setDelegate:self];
[countanimation setAutoreverses:NO];
[countanimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[countanimation setValue:@"Countdown" forKey:@"name"];
[countDown addAnimation:countanimation forKey:nil];
```

And want to hide the layer when the animation is stopped:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    if([[anim valueForKey:@"name"] isEqual:@"Countdown"])
    {
        [countDown setHidden:YES];
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the layer is flashing once with the original image (number3) and is hidden after that.

I want to know why the layer goes back to the original even though I set `removedOnCompletion` to `NO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the original image to number1, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `FillMode` property in conjunction with `removedOnCompletion` property to set first frame back to its content after `repeatCount` is over.

```
[countanimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
[countanimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
```

I think this two lines of code can help you get the required result.

Comment: I just found that these settings need to be on the group if you are using a CAAnimationGroup, rather than the individual animations, in case that helps anyone coming here

Answer (score 1):

I used  `animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;` to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4+5**

Updating Jami's answer for Swift 4 and 5

```
colorAnimation.fillMode = .both
colorAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```